# Help me finding closed form of sum of 4 elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I've been reading Wilf's Gfology and tried to calculate some complicated sum
Let's say $0<k \le n$
$$f(k,n) = \sum_{i} i(-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{i}{k-i}  $$
I will write down my calculations, i hope there is no mistake. 
I want to calculate generating function of $f(k,n)$ it is $F(k,n) = \sum_{n} f(k,n) x^n$
$$\sum_{n}x^n \sum_{i} i(-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{i}{k-i}=$$
$$\sum_{i} i(-1)^i \binom{i}{k-i} \sum_{n} \binom{n}{i} x^n=$$
$$\sum_{i} i(-1)^i \binom{i}{k-i} \frac{x^i}{(1-x)^{i+1}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{i} i(-1)^i \binom{i}{k-i} \left(\frac{x}{(1-x)}\right)^i$$
I don't really know how to proceed with this sum. 
I'd like to solve it with generating functions if it's possible. 
I will be greatful for any hints or solutions to this.

Comment: $F(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{\large i=[k/2]}^{\large k}{n\choose i}{i\choose k-i}x^i\quad\iff\quad f=F'(-1)$.

Comment: @Lucian
Hey, thanks for this great observation!
But now i'm stuck with similiar sum
$$\frac{1}{x-1} \sum_{i} \binom{i}{k-i} (\frac{x}{1-x})^i$$ i have no idea how to get rid of this last term of sum. 
I know that $$\sum_{i} \binom{i}{k-i} = F_{k+1}$$, i'd appreciate some more help, Cheers!

Comment: Depending on the parity of *k*, you are dealing with either [OEIS A$085478$](http://oeis.org/A085478) or [OEIS A$078812$](http://oeis.org/A078812).

Comment: Note that  in general selecting  some type of involved  hypergeometric expression is **not guaranteed** to produce simple closed form formulae. In your case we have $$f(n,k) = -\frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1+z}{z^{k}} 
(1-z-z^2)^{n-1} \; dz.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variant to obtain a generating function $F(x,y)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}f(k,n)x^ky^n$. It's not obvious (for me) to derive a closed formula from it. Maybe this indicates that there is no one obtainable.

Let
\begin{align*}
f(k,n)=\sum_{i}i(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{k-i}\qquad\qquad0\leq k\leq n
\end{align*}

We use with $k\geq 0$ a slightly extended range of definition.

> We now introduce the formal generating function $$F_n(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}f(k,n)x^k\qquad\qquad n\geq 0$$ and show

The following is valid

\begin{align*}
F_n(x) =-nx(1+x)(1-x-x^2)^{n-1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We observe
>   \begin{align*}
> F_n(x)&=\sum_{k\geq 0}f(k,n)x^k\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^ii\binom{n}{i}\binom{i}{k-i}x^k\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^in\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{i}{k-i}x^k\tag{2}\\
> &=n\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i-1}x^i\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{i}{k-i}x^{k-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=n\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i-1}x^i\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{i}{r}x^{r}\tag{4}\\
> &=n\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i-1}x^i(1+x)^i\\
> &=n\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n-1}{i}x^{i+1}(1+x)^{i+1}\tag{5}\\
> &=-nx(1+x)\sum_{i\geq 0}(-1)^{i}\binom{n-1}{i}x^{i}(1+x)^{i}\\
> &=-nx(1+x)\left(1-x(1+x)\right)^{n-1}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

Comment:

- In (2) we use the identity $i\binom{n}{i}=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}$
- In (3) we do some rearrangements to prepare for the index substitution in (4)
- In (4) we introduce the index $r := k-i$
- In (5) we shift the index $i$

> We now calculate the *complete* generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x,y)=\sum_{n\geq 0}F_n(x)y^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}f(k,n)x^ky^n
> \end{align*}

The following is valid

\begin{align*}
F(x,y) =-\frac{x(1+x)y}{\left(1-(1-x-x^2)y\right)^2}
\end{align*}

> We observe, using the expression (1) of the generating function $F_n(x)$
>
> \begin{align*}
> F(x,y)&=-x(1+x)\sum_{n\geq 0}n(1-x-x^2)^{n-1}y^n\\
> &=-x(1+x)y\sum_{n\geq 1}n(1-x-x^2)^{n-1}y^{n-1}\\
> &=-x(1+x)y\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)(1-x-x^2)^{n}y^{n}\tag{6}\\
> &=-x(1+x)y\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-2}{n}(1-x-x^2)^{n}(-y)^{n}\tag{7}\\
> &=-\frac{x(1+x)y}{\left(1-(1-x-x^2)y\right)^2}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

Comment:

- In (6) we shift the index $n$
- In (7) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$

Comment: Good work. Did you notice your generating function is the same as the formula from my comment? (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Hi, Marko! Thanks and no, I didn't recognise your comment. By the way, at first I also used Egorychevs residual calculus to do the calculation. But then I decided to write it this way, cause OP is currently working on Wilfs GF. :-) Regards,

Comment: This is amazing work, i learned new view on this. Many thanks Markus

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome! Thanks for your nice comment! :-)

Comment: @Chris: Hi, Chris! Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-) Two hints: In case you would like to see some kind of *higher sophisticated techniques* you might have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895184/a-new-combinatorics-identity-similar-to-catalan-number/944371#944371) of mine. If you are curious to look at an answer with *really tough calculations* you might have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045505/any-ideas-on-how-i-can-prove-this-expression/1100386#1100386). Best regards,