# Complex Analysis proof of multinomial expression

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I've recently come across the following identity 
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}
$$

A nice complex analysis proof (by Felix Marin, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/947880/117081)) follows as:
$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{}{\large\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}}&=
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{1 \over z}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\pars{1 + {1 \over z}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\color{}{\large{2n \choose n}}
\end{align}

Is there a way to generalise this technique to find the value of

$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k_1 + k_2  = 0}^n {n \choose k_1, k_2}^2
$$
where
$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2} = \frac{n!}{(n-(k_1+k_2))!k_1!k_2!}
$$
(please note that this is not the definition of the multinomial coefficient which would actually be 
$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2} = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!}
$$)

**tl;dr**

Find the value of (if possible)
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k_1 + k_2  = 0}^n {n \choose k_1, k_2}^2
$$
using complex analytical techniques.

**EDIT:**
If it helps, it is easy to show that 
$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2} = \frac{n!}{(n-(k_1+k_2))!k_1!k_2!} = {n \choose k_1} {n - k_1 \choose k_2} 
$$
A similar problem dealing with binomials and trinomials has been solved using complex analytic techniques [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/926773/117081)

Comment: If my calculation is correct, when $n = 2$, LHS = $15$ while RHS = $90$.

Comment: @roy_24601 you're 100% correct. It doesn't even hold for n=1. I've changed the question. However, any techniques used to find the value of the expression will be of most interest.

Comment: Why not use the usual notation for multinomial coefficients?

Comment: Since the answer appears to be $\binom{2n}{n} {}_3 F_2 \left( \begin{matrix} -n,-n,-n \\ 1,1/2-n \end{matrix}; \frac{1}{4}  \right)$, (which is at least a finite sum!) it seems unlikely that such a proof will work in the same way.

Comment: How did you arrive at that result with the hypergeometric function?

@Christoph, I felt that it may show some relationship between the binomial and multinomial result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** Here is a slightly different variation of the same story. These techniques are also known as *formal residual calculus for power series*. They are based upon [Cauchys residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and were introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* ([Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821845128)) to compute binomial identies.

We use the residue notation and write e.g.
\begin{align*}
\mathop{res}_z\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}\mathop{dz}
\end{align*}

In fact we will use only two aspects of this theory:

Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j$ be a *formal power series*, then

- Write the binomial coeffients as *residuals* of corresponding *formal power series*

\begin{align*}
\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{A(z)}{z^{j+1}}=a_j\tag{1}
\end{align*}

- Apply the *substitution rule* for formal power series:

\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{A(w)}{w^{j+1}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

---

> Using this notation, we show at first that
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

which is in fact the *main part* in order to simplify OPs expression
\begin{align*}
\sum_{{k_1+k_2=0}\atop{k_1,k_2\geq 0}}\binom{n}{n-(k_1+k_2),k_1,k_2}^2
\end{align*}
We write the trinomial coefficient in the expression above in standard form using the notation for *multinomial coefficients*.

> We observe that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u^{k+1}}\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{k+1}}\tag{5}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{k}}\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{k+1}}\tag{6}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{n}\tag{7}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{2n}}{u^{n+1}}\\
> &=[z^n](1+u)^{2n}\tag{8}\\
> &=\binom{2n}{n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we extend the upper limit of the sum without changing the value since we are only adding zeroes.
- In (5) we rewrite the binomial coefficients using residues according to (1)
- In (6) we do some rearrangements to prepare for the substitution rule
- In (7) we apply the substitution rule according to (2)
- In (8) we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient $a_n$ in $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j$. Observe that following is valid when using the *formal residual operator* $\mathop{res}$

$$\mathop{res}_z\frac{A(z)}{z^{n+1}}=[z^{-1}]\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}A(z)=[z^n]A(z)$$

$$$$

> We now show that OPs expression is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{k_1+k_2=0}\atop{k_1,k_2\geq 0}}\binom{n}{n-(k_1+k_2),k_1,k_2}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}^2\binom{2k}{k}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
>
> *Note:* The RHS of (9) is stated as integer sequence [A002893](https://oeis.org/search?q=A002893&language=german&go=Suche) in *OEIS* which  indicates, that further simplifications are not feasible.

Since OP already stated, that 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{n-(k_1+k_2),k_1,k_2}=\frac{n!}{\left(n-(k_1+k_2)\right)!k_1!k_2!}=\binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}
\end{align*}

> we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{k_1+k_2=0}\atop{k_1,k_2\geq 0}}&\binom{n}{n-(k_1+k_2),k_1,k_2}^2\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^{n}\sum_{k_2=0}^{n-k_1}\binom{n}{k_1}^2\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}^2\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k_1}^2\left(\sum_{k_2=0}^{n-k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}^2\right)\tag{10}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k_1}^2\binom{2n-2k_1}{n-k_1}\tag{11}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2k}{k}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe the residual calculus was used in  (10) and (11) by applying (3). Everything else was done with elementary transformations.

---

*Note:* Further applications of the *formal residual calculus* are not promising. We could e.g. use the identity
$$\binom{2k}{k}=(-4)^k\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}$$ and then try to apply the substitution rule (2) again:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}&\binom{n}{k}^2\binom{2k}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2(-4)^k\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u^{k+1}}\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{k+1}}
(-4)^k\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{z^{k+1}}\\
&=\mathop{res}_{u,w}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u}\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{4}{uw}\right)^k
\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{z^{k+1}}\\
&=\mathop{res}_{u,w}\frac{(1+u)^{n}}{u}\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w}
\left(1-\frac{4}{uw}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
regrettably further simplifications similar to (7) are not feasible. But of course this technique is often helpful, see e.g. this answer regarding [central binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895184/a-new-combinatorics-identity-similar-to-catalan-number/944371#944371).

Comment: Wow, this is very illuminating. Thank you for the techniques you've presented here and clearly explained. This will surely help a lot of people apply complex analytic techniques to combinatorial problems.

Comment: @Black: You're welcome! Thanks for your nice comment. :-) The two aspects from Egorychevs book I've used are only the tip of the iceberg. His book is a deep source of knowledge and inspiration for solving binomial sums. I also deeply appreciate the little paper about the *bracket notation* of the *coefficient of* operator by the great Don Knuth. Reading it provides a glimpse to us what he might have thought about notational conventions when he was inventing/creating $\TeX$ for us!  Best regards,