# Proof of Vandermonde's Identity using a "different approach" using complex integration

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Hi I'd like to know if the following proof of Vandermonde's Identity is correct (is really easy):

Let $m,n,r$ be natural numbers such that $r\le \min \{m,n\}$.  The Vandermonde's Identity gives us that $$ \binom{m+n}r = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk \binom n{r-k} $$

$\bf{Solution}$ Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle $\lvert z\lvert =1$. Now since $${m \choose r}= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma}\frac{(1+z)^m}{z^{r+1}} dz$$

Then

\begin{align}  2\pi i \binom{m+n}r= \int _{\gamma}\frac{(1+z)^{m+n}}{z^{r+1}} dz &= \int _{\gamma}\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{r+1}}\sum_{k=0}^m  {m \choose k}z^k \,dz\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m  { m\choose k}\int_\gamma \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{r-k+1}} dz \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m 2\pi i { m\choose k} {n\choose r-k} \end{align}

For all $k>r$, we set ${n\choose r-k}=0$, i.e., the left-hand side is zero and imply the desired identity

$$ \binom{m+n}r = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk \binom n{r-k} $$

Thanks :)

Comment: @gt6989b Do you think is correct?

Comment: yes, i think this is right

Comment: @gt6989b I like it because is incredible easy.  Even more than the usual approach using generating functions. Thanks :)

Comment: @JoseAntonio Instead of using generating functions, I think an easy combinatoric proof is also possible.

Comment: Nice use of complex calculus. A combinatorial proof : Let A have m members and let B have n members with $ A\cap B = \phi$. For k from 0 to r , compute the number of ways to choose a set with r members  with k of them in A and r-k of them in B. Now sum over k.

Comment: @user254665 Thank you; a similar exercise is in Conway's Complex Analysis and when I was working with this identity yesterday I had the idea, why no put the contour integral to show it. Could you explain a little bit more this approach, please? I'm not very good using a combinatorial approach.

Comment: @user254665 The only point where I'm not completely sure is to set ${n, \choose k} \equiv 0$ when $k<0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the question off the unanswered list. Yes, your approach is correct.

See [Complex Analysis proof of multinomial expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215985) for something in the same spirit.

Comment: Thanks. Is completely correct to set ${n \choose r-k}=0$ for $k>r$?

Comment: Wow I've never seen this approach. I think is amazing, thanks for the link :)